# Привести список телефонов к определенному виду

Tags: python, pandas, анализ-данных

Df

```
       Телефон
    0   4956895325
    1  84951491991
    2   9037481292
    3  74992506983
    4  84957975576
    5  749567348106039156
```

Как выбрать в каждой строке первые 11 цифр? Если в строке 10 цифр , то первой подставить 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df["Телефон"] = df["Телефон"].str.rjust(11, "7")
```

результат:

```
In [199]: df
Out[199]:
              Телефон
0         74956895325
1         84951491991
2         79037481292
3         74992506983
4         84957975576
5  749567348106039156
```